# Custom errors in ASP .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-error-pages

I tried to set up custom error handling in ASP .Net MVC Application. In Web.config I have this :

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error/page500.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/page404.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/page500.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <clear/>
    <error statusCode="404" responseMode="File" path="/Error/page404.html"/>
    <error statusCode="500" responseMode="File" path="/Error/page500.html"/>
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

And When I try url's like :

```
http://localhost:49376/private/aaa
```

I can see my 404 custom error page

[image]

And when I try the url

```
http://localhost:49376/private/aaa<
```

I can also see my 500 custom error page

[image]

But when try urls like :

```
http://localhost:49376/private/aaa/foo/bar
```

I get the IIS default error page. And when I try

```
http://localhost:49376/private/aaa<script></script>
```

I get the Runtime Default error page.

What am I missing ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that is an IIS protection thing, it will filter certain URLs that have potentially invalid or dangerous content in them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but it could be your elmah config. Read more about it here, espesially in the comments section: http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/01/aspnet-session-hijacking-with-google.html?m=1

I think this is a known Elmah issue if you set up the config a little wrong

So long story short, try this in your config:

```
<location path="elmah.axd">
  <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error/page500.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/page404.aspx"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/page500.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" 
        type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admin" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD"
        type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"
        preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <clear/>
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="File" path="/Error/page404.html"/>
      <error statusCode="500" responseMode="File" path="/Error/page500.html"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: But I still get the IIS Default error page for the url like 'http://localhost:49376/private/aaa/sss/sss'